# Why is one folder on my Samsung Galaxy SII not being properly showed on PC?

Tags: file-system, usb-connection-mode, file-management

There is one folder on my device (not in the microSD card) with mp3 files that used to work perfectly but suddenly started to cause a malfunction when I try to open it on a PC. It is said to have no files in it and all of the other folders stop being recognized after this until I reconnect the device. However I can always get access to the folder content through the cellphone file manager system: the problem is only happening when connected to a PC via USB cable.

Does anybody know why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Device: Samsung Galaxy SII.

Comment: Maybe the folder is in root directory, which doesn't shows up when connected to PC

Comment: I don't think so because it used to show. Then, suddenly, it started to appear as an empty folder. Also, other folders in the same place work normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution (actually I even had left it behind...). Sometime after I posted this question I create another folder and after a while it began to have the same problem. Today I realized that both folder had one common caracteristic: they contained characters beyond the basic [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) (one was called "Músicas" and the other, "Vídeos". When I renamed them ("Musicas" and "Videos", respectively), the issue was solved.